# Adding class based on td value using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have rows in the following way.

```
<table id="tblInbox">
<tbody>    
    <tr class='active'><td>Daily Price</td><td>1</td><td>Santosh</td></tr>
    <tr class='active'><td>Daily Price</td><td>2</td><td>Star</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Weekly Price</td><td>3</td><td>Zakeer</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Weekly Price</td><td>4</td><td>Ubed</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Weekly Price</td><td>5</td><td>xyz/td></tr>
    <tr><td>Daily Price</td><td>6</td><td>India</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Daily Price</td><td>7</td><td>Australia</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I will display rows which are having class 'active' by using

```
function displayActiveRows(){ // Displaying active rows
    $("#tblInbox tbody tr").each( function(){ 
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) { // If the row has class.
        console.log("has class");
        $(this).show(); // Display the row.
    } else {                
        $(this).hide(); // Hide the row.
    }       
    });
}
```

On pressing "Next" button, I'd like to add class to only next 2 0r 10 (whatever the count is) rows which are having first td value as "Daily price" by removing the class to existing rows. My code is like this.

```
$(document).on('click','#nextPage',function(){ // Clicking Next Button.
    // Remove class to already existing class rows.
    $('.active').removeClass('active');     
    // Confused here. 
 });
```

Can you suggest me, guys?

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QN8er/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny, Thanks for the fiddle. But, Arun, you misundestood my question. I'll display only the rows which are having the class 'active' on load also, on clicking next, I've to check all the rows with that td text and add the class 'active'

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QN8er/3/ I've changed the fiddle. Please check it.

Comment: in that case also it is working fine isn't it

Comment: @ArunPJohny, No dear, It will show the existing rows also with that class. If I keep $('.active').removeClass('active'). It doesn't show me anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/?s=first-child) and [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QN8er/6/)**

```
$(document).on('click','#nextPage',function(){ // Clicking Next Button.  
    $('.active :first-child:contains("Daily Price")').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive'); 
});
```

To check irrespective of tr class you can use tr in selector instead of .active

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QN8er/7/)**

```
$(document).on('click','#nextPage',function(){ // Clicking Next Button.  
    $('tr :first-child:contains("Daily Price")').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive'); 
});
```

To toggle class beteen rows you need to iterate using each.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QN8er/11/)**

```
$(document).on('click','#nextPage',function(){ // Clicking Next Button.  
    $('tr :first-child:contains("Daily Price")').each(function(){       
       if($(this).parent()[0].className === '')
           $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        else
        if($(this).parent()[0].className == 'active')        
           $(this).parent().removeClass('active');  

    });
});
```

You can use conditional opertator also

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QN8er/12/)**

```
$(document).on('click','#nextPage',function(){ // Clicking Next Button.  
    $('tr :first-child:contains("Daily Price")').each(function(){       
        $(this).parent()[0].className = $(this).parent()[0].className === "active" ? "" : "active";
    });
});
```

Comment: I want to add the class to the td text containing "Daily Price" . I'll remove the class by simply $('.active').removeClass('active'); By checking all the rows, I need to add the class with the condition of td text.

Comment: Intially you're showing the rows with green color. That's fine. But, when you click next, It has to remove the existing class to first  two rows, and check the other rows with that text. I've to show only 2 rows at one time.

Comment: I have add new solution which is for tr and does not look for .active, is this what you want

Comment: Brother Little part is correct. At first you're showing the first two rows with green color. That's perfectly fine. When you click next, the next two rows which has that td text should be in green color. Already existing green color rows should be in normal thing.i.e. removing 'active' class. I have to show only two rows at a time.

Comment: Worked like a charm..Thank you Adil

Comment: do you have any personal email id?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#tblInbox tbody tr").children("td:contains('Daily Price')").parent().addClass('active')
```